# VueJS 2 Directives insert event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new VueJS Student, and i was trying to do a directive, and i stopped because i dont know why i can't get the element. What's am i doing wrong? I just want to get the `el` element.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7r9x60ps/) or the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="vue-app">
    <ul>
      <li v-test v-for="item in itens">
        {{item.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <span id="directiveLog"></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.directive('test', {
  inserted: function (el) {
        document.querySelector('#directiveLog').innerHTML = el;
  }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',

  data: {
    itens:[
     {name: "hello"},
     {name: "fun"},
     {name: "world"}
   ] 
  }

});
```

Comment: Check your console log: VueJS is not loaded because you're hotlinking from a URL that prevents you from doing that. Try loading it from a CDN (like from [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js)), and your directive should work: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/7r9x60ps/1/. Note that a HTML node is an object, so setting an innerHTML (which accepts a string) to the node (an object) will not work. You probably meant: `document.querySelector('#directiveLog').innerHTML = el.innerHTML`

Comment: Vue is loaded, otherwise nothing would have rendered. It's loaded twice is the problem and the second one is Vue 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter 'el' in function inserted(el) {...} - it is your element where v-test is inserted.

```js
 Vue.directive('test', {
        inserted: function (el) {
            document.querySelector('#directiveLog').innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
  }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',

  data: {
    itens:[
     {name: "hello"},
     {name: "fun"},
     {name: "world"}
   ]
  }

});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <div v-test class="container" id="vue-app">
                <ul>
                  <li v-for="item in itens">
                    {{item.name}}
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <span id="directiveLog"></span>
            </div>
```